# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mvapp_vep'

Tags: python-3.x, django

tengo el problema que cuando ejecuto un archivo python (tests_plandetrabajo.py) me da el siguiente error:

(env) PS C:\Python\proyecto> & c:/Python/proyecto/env/Scripts/python.exe c:/Python/proyecto/mvapp_vep/tests/tests_plandetrabajo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python\proyecto\mvapp_vep\tests\tests_plandetrabajo.py", line 1, in 
from mvapp_vep.models import PlanTrabajo
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mvapp_vep'**

el codigo del .py que ejecuto es:

[image: VS lo reconoce no marca error alguno en el from]

no he podido encontrar la manera de solucionar el código. Hice la consulta a Copilot y todo lo que me dice lo hago y sigo exactamente con el mismo problema.
Gracias

Comment: Para que la importación absoluta (que no es tipo con "from . import ...") funcione, el paquete a importar debe estar presente en sys.path (una lista de directorios en los que podría estar el paquete). Agregaste la carpeta mvapp_vep a sys.path? Probaste usando importaciones relativas, las cuales en mi opinión son la mejor opción?

Comment: Por cierto, te recomiendo para futura referencia que añadas a la duda toda la info necesaria. En este caso, el arbol de directorios del paquete. Si no fuera por que publicaste el traceback completo, ayudarte sería más dificil. Además, explicar tus intentos ayudaría a evitar que te propongamos cosas que ya probaste.